# Reading CSV files from DataLake into Python Flask Application

Tags: python, azure-data-lake

I need to read some CSVs available in Azure Data Lake Gen 2 container from my python flask application which is hosted on Azure app service.

```
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id,client_id,client_secret) 
service = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="https://xxx.dfs.core.windows.net/",credential=credential)

     #create a file system in ADLS Gen2
     file_system_client = service.create_file_system(file_system="")
     directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("")

     file_client = directory_client.get_file_client("File.csv")

     download=file_client.download_file()

     downloaded_bytes = download.readall()

     with open("./sample.txt", "wb") as my_file:
         my_file.write(downloaded_bytes)
         my_file.close()
```

not able to authenticate using service principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to replicate the issue with given code, I was unable to connect to the ADLS account I got below authorization error:

[image]

I have added service principle with  `storage data contributor`  role to the ADLS account as follows:
Step1:
Go to IAM of ADLS account, clicked on Add role assignment as mentioned below:

[image]

Step2:
Search for `storage data contributor` role and select it as mentioned below:

[image]

Step3:
Select the service principle as mentioned below:

[image]

After successful role assignment I run below code to read csv file from ADLS gen2 account:

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

TENANT_ID = "<tenantId>"
CLIENT_ID = "<clientId>"
CLIENT_SECRET = "<clientSecret>"
ACCOUNT_NAME = "<accountName>"
FILE_SYSTEM_NAME = "<containeName>"
SOURCE_DIRECTORY = "<sourceFilePath>"
SOURCE_FILE_NAME = "<fileName>.csv"
LOCAL_DESTINATION_PATH = "<targetFilePath>/<fileName>.txt"

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(TENANT_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)

dataLakeServiceClient = DataLakeServiceClient(
    account_url="https://<accountName>.dfs.core.windows.net",
    credential=credentials
)

file_system_client = dataLakeServiceClient.get_file_system_client(FILE_SYSTEM_NAME)
source_directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client(SOURCE_DIRECTORY)
source_file_client = source_directory_client.get_file_client(SOURCE_FILE_NAME) 
source_file_contents = source_file_client.download_file().readall()

with open(LOCAL_DESTINATION_PATH, "wb") as local_file:
    local_file.write(source_file_contents)

print(f"CSV file copied to {LOCAL_DESTINATION_PATH} successfully.")
```

It run successfully without any error:

[image]

The file read successfully:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, can we also connect with ALDS using account name and key?

Comment: Yes you can connect